# Explorer.exe - No such interface supported and other issues

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

The problem started when I uninstalled my ATI graphics driver and i used a driver cleaner.

After i restarted win7 and it got to POST the screen just went completely blank. So i Used system restore from the repair menu to get back on.

I found out that if I ran chkdsk the display just goes black after restart on startup and i have to use system restore to get back on windows7 not sure why this is.

When i right click desktop and choose 'Screen Resolution' it says No such interface supported. Also when I click items such as device manager in the windows explorer it does not do anything.

I have tried re-registering the DLLS but that did not do anything.

Comment: Have you scanned for malware?

Comment: its not malware. this happend right after i used "driver sweeper" i'm pretty sure it must have removed some important windows files

Comment: I smell scam...

Comment: @Hello71 & @Moab   Not a scam or malware, it's just badly written software. See my post.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read [here](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=279&threadid=145658) on the AMD forums, the relevant bit is this:
(The relevant text is in bold)

> **Apparently Driver Sweeper deletes
>   (cleans up) entries and files for ATI
>   video drivers that are actually part
>   of the original Windows 7 install
>   package.**  When you attempt to install
>   Win 7 SP1, the installer finds that
>   these entries and files are missing
>   and fails with an error code
>   0x800f0a13.

The author of the software is looking into a fix. Reference is [here](http://forum.phyxion.net/viewtopic.php?id=15)

> I will look into this for the next
>   version of Driver Sweeper, I'll make
>   sure that the restore of Driver
>   Sweeper will be able to restore all
>   the files and directories. Driver
>   Sweeper always has backups of all
>   files and directories, if it's not
>   possible to create a backup the
>   file/directory is not deleted.

So it looks like some files cannot be restored by the user or the program (at this time)

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is related to windows registry entries and you have system restore points enabled you should be able to navigate to Start>All Programs>Accessories>System Tools>System Restore and select the point where you either installed or ran the driver cleaner.  This will reset any changes to the registry.

If it also ripped out any important files it's a bit of a craps shoot.  You can try downloading and re-installing the video driver which would resolve any missing driver files such as DLLs but if it took out any required files from windows then you may be looking at having to run a backup and then run a full system restore in order to remedy the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue on Windows 2012, where it suddenly stopped opening ***Explorer.exe*** on Windows logon, and displayed a black desktop.
Any attempt to load Explorer.exe failed with error "***No such interface supported***".

I found a solution in http://www.w7forums.com/threads/no-such-interface-supported.17543/ :

From Task Manager (CTRL + SHIFT + ESC), open CMD and run:

```
FOR /R C:\Windows\ %G IN (*.dll) DO "%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" /s "%G"
```

It will take some time and will open many Runtime errors messages, you can close them all.
Once completed, restart windows ( `shutdown -r -t 0` ), and hold fingers...